# Does the output of valgrind still reliable when it reports the 'impossible' happened: LibVEX called failure_exit()

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Here is the brief log:

```
# valgrind --error-limit=no --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck /mnt/aarch64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 ./program 
==12104== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12104== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12104== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12104== Command: /mnt/aarch64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 ./program 
==12104== 



vex: priv/host_arm64_defs.c:2796 (genSpill_ARM64): Assertion `offsetB < 4096' failed.
vex storage: T total 4207069920 bytes allocated
vex storage: P total 0 bytes allocated

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   LibVEX called failure_exit().

host stacktrace:
==12104==    at 0x5803F488: show_sched_status_wrk (m_libcassert.c:406)
==12104==    by 0x5803F5C7: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:477)
==12104==    by 0x5803F7FB: panic (m_libcassert.c:553)
==12104==    by 0x5803F7FB: vgPlain_core_panic_at (m_libcassert.c:558)
==12104==    by 0x5803F81F: vgPlain_core_panic (m_libcassert.c:563)
==12104==    by 0x5805481B: failure_exit (m_translate.c:761)
==12104==    by 0x5811E043: vex_assert_fail (main_util.c:245)
==12104==    by 0x5817A897: genSpill_ARM64 (host_arm64_defs.c:2796)
==12104==    by 0x58172217: spill_vreg (host_generic_reg_alloc3.c:338)
==12104==    by 0x5817324F: doRegisterAllocation_v3 (host_generic_reg_alloc3.c:1280)
==12104==    by 0x5811CD97: libvex_BackEnd (main_main.c:1133)
==12104==    by 0x5811CD97: LibVEX_Translate (main_main.c:1236)
==12104==    by 0x58056FCB: vgPlain_translate (m_translate.c:1830)
==12104==    by 0x58092A27: handle_chain_me (scheduler.c:1169)
==12104==    by 0x580954A7: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1514)
==12104==    by 0x580D8E8F: thread_wrapper (syswrap-linux.c:101)
==12104==    by 0x580D8E8F: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:154)
==12104==    by 0x580D916F: vgModuleLocal_start_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:328)
==12104==    by 0x580A68D3: ??? (in /mnt/aarch64/lib/valgrind/memcheck-arm64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=3
```

I want to known whether the reset output of `valgrind` is still meaningful for pointing out the memory leak in the program when it reports the said error(i.e. `the 'impossible' happened: LibVEX called failure_exit()`)

Updated:
The program does run, I can see many stack strace,e.g:

```
Thread 1: status = VgTs_WaitSys syscall 98 (lwpid 12168)
==12168==    at 0x6E85274: syscall (in /lib/libc-2.31.so)
==12168==    by 0x6B99FF3: std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base
...

Thread 2:
...
```

Comment: The program doesn't run, then, does it?

Comment: @user253751 The program does run, There are many information about stacks. I updated the post.

Comment: I guess it is probably just showing you what the process was doing when valgrind crashed.

Comment: @user253751 If I understand you correctly, you mean the output below the error(i.e. `LibVEX called failure_exit()`) reported by valgrind is meaningless\helpless to find the memory leak of the target program. Am I right?

Comment: The fact that "there are stack traces" doesn't mean there are memory leaks. When it detects memory leaks, it prints something about memory leaks. When it doesn't print something about memory leaks, then it's not telling you the stack traces of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if Valgrind reports some errors and then encounters an internal error, those initial reports should be valid.

In the case of the message that you show, the first report is an internal error related to the virtualization of the ARM aarch64 CPU. That's only useful for Valgrind developers.

Try running Valgrind with -d -v. There will be a lot of output, but you should see

- `syswrap- run_a_thread_NORETURN(tid=1): pre-thread_wrapper` that is the guest executable starting
- a load of gdbsrv messages
- a mix of REDIR and mallocrf/hashtbl messages as the guest startup code invokes ld.so to load shared libraries

I can't tell where you get the subsequent traces from - could be trace options, more likely from the assert.

Comment: ***those initial reports should be valid.*** What about the output **below** the errors reported. Is it ***still reliable or meaningful***?

Comment: No. The guest is terminating because of a Valgrind error. Any still in use messages are meaningless.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. What is `guest`? What is `still in use messages`? Could you please explain that in simpler words?

Comment: Valgrind itself is the host. The application that you are testing is the guest (sometimes the client). On termination, Valgrind will print a leak summary. This leaks will be a combination of `definite`, `indirect`, `possible` and `still in use`.

Comment: In honest, there is no such messages indeed. I amazed at there is no 
information about `definite`, `indirect`, `possible` and `still in use`.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell from the fragments that you posted. I can only see things that are related to Valgrind triggering an assert and then printing its own stacktrace and also the guest threads stacktraces.